# positioning in table by adding font for sorting

Tags: html, css

What is the proper way to accomplish the right position of the font for sorting even the words of the column title becomes more than two. Here is the sample of my table:

[image: table sample]

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sortable">
        <div>
            <span>Name</span>
            <span class="icons unsorted"></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th cliass="sortable">
        <dv>
            <span>Testifying Experience</span>
            <span class="icons unsorted"></span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

CSS:

```
thead th {
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #1797C0;
  padding: 3px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
thead th div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Before, I'm just using span without putting them inside the div and by setting the `th` to `relative` position and the `span` for unsorted icon to `absolute`, however it only works for one word and does not for more than one word.

Comment: Depending on where you want them: top, middle, aligned with last line.

Comment: i think he is not asking to align right ... he is asking the right method to align

Comment: check the answer if it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using `span` and add the class for font icon: `<span class="icons unsorted"></span>`, I used `background-image` and `background-position: center right 8px` which won't affect the font icon positioning whenever you have more than one word column title.

See my [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz5pktq9/1/).